# GetType("ClassName).GetMethod("MethodName") throws error

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I'm trying to understand more about Assembly class and its methods and there is an example as following on this [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as following:

However, method:  `assem.GetType("Example").GetMethod("SampleMethod")`  throws an exception error and complains for not having an object reference.

Seems the method before this method returns null  as well. Any idea?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly:AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.2000.0")]

public class Example
{
    private int factor;
    public Example(int f)
    {
        factor = f;
    }

    public int SampleMethod(int x) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("\nExample.SampleMethod({0}) executes.", x);
        return x * factor;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Assembly assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        Console.WriteLine("Assembly Full Name:");
        Console.WriteLine(assem.FullName);

        // The AssemblyName type can be used to parse the full name.
        AssemblyName assemName = assem.GetName();
        Console.WriteLine("\nName: {0}", assemName.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}.{1}", 
            assemName.Version.Major, assemName.Version.Minor);

        Console.WriteLine("\nAssembly CodeBase:");
        Console.WriteLine(assem.CodeBase);

        // Create an object from the assembly, passing in the correct number
        // and type of arguments for the constructor.
        Object o = assem.CreateInstance("Example", false, 
            BindingFlags.ExactBinding, 
            null, new Object[] { 2 }, null, null);

        // Make a late-bound call to an instance method of the object.    
        MethodInfo m = assem.GetType("Example").GetMethod("SampleMethod");
        Object ret = m.Invoke(o, new Object[] { 42 });
        Console.WriteLine("SampleMethod returned {0}.", ret);

        Console.WriteLine("\nAssembly entry point:");
        Console.WriteLine(assem.EntryPoint);
    }
}
```

/* This code example produces output similar to the following:

Assembly Full Name:
source, Version=1.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Name: source
Version: 1.0

Assembly CodeBase:
file:///C:/sdtree/AssemblyClass/cs/source.exe

Example.SampleMethod(42) executes.
SampleMethod returned 84.

Assembly entry point:
Void Main()
 */

Comment: I'm going to guess `GetType(..)` returns null. Please work on *isolating* the actual problem - if GetType does return null, then GetMethod is entirely extraneous.

Comment: So you've given us a program which *does* work... what about a program which *doesn't* work? (That code definitely works for me... it's not really clear whether you're running that exact code and having problems, or what...)

Comment: I can reproduce this _if_ I put this code within a namespace.  Given that, -1 for not including the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at Assembly.CreateInstance method (you can find the description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.createinstance.aspx))
you can see that in this code:

```
 Object o = assem.CreateInstance("Example", false, 
        BindingFlags.ExactBinding, 
        null, new Object[] { 2 }, null, null);
```

You are simply not really asigning any value to 'o'.

Then, as I said before , you are not returning it by the :

```
assem.GetType("Example")
```

adding the namespace will really solve the problem.

In the future , try isolating the problem to find what is wrong. simlpy helps debugging